# Implement Asynctask in retrieving data from my database

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

How can I achieve this one? I'm creating a registration form. I don't want to wait to finish executing the retrieval of data from my database before continuing to another field. Example: My first field is the student id, now after entering data there, it will check from the database using HTTPUrlConnection if it is already used. But sometimes especially if im using free webhost, it tooks time to finish yet sometimes my app is not responding. What I want is to let it check while I'm filling up other fields.

sample code from my email validation

```
 public boolean checkIfSameEmail(String data) {
    try {
        String accountURL =  DataClass.localAddress + "/android_php/account.php";
        URL url = new URL(accountURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int x = 0; x < parentArray.length(); x++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(x);

            if (finalObject.getString("email").equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                System.out.println("Here!!");
                return true;

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

then

```
  edtEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            edtEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!edtEmail.hasFocus()) {
                        getData();
                        edtEmailET(sEmail);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Do i have to use thread, asynctask or something? I'm beginner here so i really don't have ideas. I just use Asynctask when inserting data from the database, I just learned it from a tutorial, maybe i will use onPreExecute() here?

UPDATE:

Inside edtEmailET is this:

```
    public boolean edtEmailET(String Email) {

    if (Email.replace(" ", "").isEmpty()) {
        tilEmail.setError("You can't leave this empty.");
        return true;
    } else if (!checkIfValidEmail(Email) == true) {
        tilEmail.setError("Invalid e - mail address");
        return true;
    } else if (checkIfSameEmail(Email) == true) {
        tilEmail.setError("E-mail already used.");
        return true;
    } else {
        tilEmail.setError(null);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AsyncTask should cover your need.
You could use a structure such as:

```
class VerifyEmailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    // use doInBackground() to make network calls, the returned value is
    // sent to onPostExecute()
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... data) {
        return checkIfSameEmail(data[0]);
    }

    // use onPostExecute() to perform any desired operation on the UI
    // with the result from your network call
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            // do something
            Log.d("VerifyEmailTask", "Here!!");
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
new VerifyEmailTask().execute("email@domain.com");
```

You should read the documentation for AsyncTask (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: just one more question, i have also checkIfSameUsername, checkIfStudIDExists, checkIfSameStudID and more validation methods, should i make each of them an asynctask class?

Comment: Technically you could, and it would have you covered, but you can use your abstraction and object oriented knowledge to structure your classes and methods so as to only need one AsyncTask.

Comment: Okay got it. But I have an error:
"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: I updated my question check it out. Inside edtEmailET there is an if-statement

Comment: That error happens when you try to modify the UI from any thread other than the main one. Keep in mind that anything performed in AsyncTask's doInBackground() is performed in a background thread and you should update the UI in onPostExecute()

Comment: Can you help me how can i modify my code with the implementation of Asynctask? Another question is I have a button register, how will the button know first if there's no more background processing?